# How to change HSRP version 1 to 2 without downtime?

Tags: cisco, switch, network, hsrp

We have running `HSRP` in production but its running on `version 1` now i want to change it to `version 2` so is there a way to do without any downtime or disturb live traffic?

Comment: That's simply not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of a way to achieve this within the limits of "same set of router interfaces of the same pair/group of routers".

HSRPv1 and v2 are:

- a) incompatible and
- b) mutually exclusive on one given (sub)interface of a router and
- c) conflicting when implemented in parallel with the same standby ip
  addresses. That much, I assume, you already figured out.

In short: I don't think this is possible to achive without any influence on the live traffic.

Some trickery with temporay additional routers, secondary standby IP addresses and relying on the fact that a router sends a gratuitous ARP for the given standby address when it goes active might bring down the interruption to just a few seconds. However, that is neither pretty nor simple. To elaborate, more information about the given network situation would be needed.

Eventually, scheduling some downtime might be the best (non-)solution. After all downtime won't take longer than it takes HSRPv2 to go *active*, which in turn depends on the timers you configure.